# summarize a list by object with totals, using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm new to sh shell scripting.
How can I write this script in terms of `sort` and `grep`?

There is an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script that sums up all the values of a list by group.

```
awk '{ arr[$1]+=$2 }
     END {
       for (key in arr) printf("%s\t%s\n", key, arr[key])
     }' "$@" |
sort +0n -1
```

Suppose the file:

```
A 8
B 3
A 2
B 4
```

Output is:

```
A 10
B 7
```

All I have now is `cat "$1" | sort` but how do I get hold of the left and right columns individually without using `awk`?

I'm stuck on how to get the first column into an array with its values to the right respectively.

Comment: I believe using `awk` will not make it lesser shell script in any way. May I know why do you want to avoid `awk`?

Comment: I'm just curious how this would work without using `awk`, but I'm having trouble making this work.

Comment: So you expect us to figure out an acceptable way under your arbitrary rules? Can I use perl? Also, if `awk` isn't acceptable you should probably remove it from the tag list.

Comment: It seems odd to sort `A` and `B` numerically.

Comment: I'm more interested in this working with shell script. I'll remove `awk` from the tag list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `bash` 4.x or a sufficiently recent `ksh`, you can try:

```
declare -A sum   # Use typeset -A sum in ksh, which also works in bash
cat <<'EOF' |
A 8
B 3
A 2
B 4
EOF
{
while read key value
do
    ((sum[$key]+=$value))
done
for key in "${!sum[@]}"
do echo "$key ${sum[$key]}"
done
} | sort
```

The old-style notation `+0n -1` is now expressed as `-k 1n,1` and means sort the first column (the key values) numerically.  Since the key values are `A` and `B`, this is not very helpful, so I've left the sort criteria off.  What would make more sense to me would be `-k 2n` or `-k 2nr` to sort by the sum in increasing or decreasing order.

The `bash` manual recommends `declare -A` over `typeset -A`, but both work; `ksh` requires `typeset -A`.

Comment: It means you aren't using `bash` 4.x (or perhaps you're using it as `/bin/sh`, in which case it might not recognize `declare`). Which shell are you using?  If you're using `ksh` (Korn Shell), you need to use `typeset` instead of `declare`, as noted in the answer. If you're using `csh` or `tcsh` or something of that ilk, you're on a hiding to nothing. If you're using original Bourne shell, you're on a hiding to nothing. If you're using `zsh`, it is supposed to be the all-singing, all-dancing extension of all sorts of shells; I'd half expect it to work, but I don't know enough to pontificate.

Comment: Oh, and in case you had not gathered, all shells are not equal. Some are more powerful than others.  If you want reliability and portability, you'll continue to use `awk`.  If your shell does not support associative arrays, you'll continue to use `awk`.  Actually, you'll probably use awk anyway.  But you asked how it could be done, and with the right shells, I showed how it could be done.  I tested both `bash` 4.2 and `ksh` (`sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08`) on Mac OS X 10.9.1.  The `ksh` is provided by Apple; I built the `bash` myself.

Comment: In case others are curious too: "be on a hiding to nothing" is a British idiom meaning "unlikely to succeed, or be unlikely to gain much advantage if one does". `bash`, when invoked as `sh`, does recognize `declare` in principle, at least on OS X. A pre-v4 `bash` - with no support for associative arrays - will complain with `declare: -A: invalid option`.

Comment: To make the code work in `zsh`, replace `"${!sum[@]}"` with `${(k)sum}`.

Comment: @mklement0: hmmm...yes, I suppose the British idiom probably does need translating.  Thanks for the info on the `zsh` syntax.

Comment: @F.Hauri: no — if you have a _poor_ shell without associative array support, this won't work.  If you need associative arrays but your shell doesn't support them, then you would be foolhardy to try translating the `awk` into shell code.  I am not convinced that using shell rather than `awk` is a good idea in the first place. However, if you have a sufficiently powerful shell, then my code shows how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE="input"
eval $(sed '/^$/d;s/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\1=\$((\$\1 + \2))/' $FILE)
eval $(sed '/^$/d;s/ .*$//' $FILE | sort -u | sed 's/.*/echo "& = \$&";/')
```

The first sed expression creates lines in the form of `A=$(($A + 8))`. The second one generates `echo "A = $A";` expressions.

*Gives:*

```
A = 10
B = 7
```